# Why is the magnetic unit twice the electric one in CGS?

Tags: magnetostatics

In CGS system the electric unit is the esu or statcoulomb equal to $2.08*10^9$ charges and two such units repel with a force of $1$ dyne.

Magnetic force ratio is $v^2/c^2$, therefore the magnetic unit is set equal to 1 $esu * C = 6.24*10 ^{19}$. Tho such units on a wire 1 cm long, at 1 cm distance exert a pull of 2 dynes.

How's that, and why disdn't they choose the same unit of force 1 dyne?

Incidentally, does that imply that the electric force of 1 dyne refer to the total pull and that the force of one unit on the other is just half dyne?

Comment: why the downvote, what's wrong with this question?

Comment: (Not I was the down) I suggest don't bother on single quasi-random downs, they happen everywhere. But a little bit of finetuning of your latex skills could make a much better look to your questions and it decreases the chance of similar events significantly. And changing your name from user104372 to a normal one, too.

Comment: +1 This is a very legitimate question, but I would take @peterh advice as something to keep in mind

Comment: Actually, on second thought after checking what that CGS is I don't quite get how they calculate $v^2$. This seems so vague that I guess my vague answer  needs to disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factor of two, i.e. "two dynes", appears because the derivation of the force between wires produces the factor naturally ([Ampere's force law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_force_law)):
$$\frac {F_m} {L} = 2 k_A \frac {I_1 I_2 } {r}$$
In SI units, $k_A=\mu_0/(4\pi)$. The factor of two may be viewed as $4\pi / (2\pi)$ because the most natural description of charges and fields assumes that the flux is divided over $4\pi r^2$ of the spherical area; however, the wires have a cylinder around whose area is $2\pi r \cdot \Delta L$. So converting from the natural sphere (from the 3D laws) to the situation with the circle gives the factor of two.

This allows the fundamental equations, Maxwell's equations, to avoid all factors such as $2$ (although there is always some question where exactly one writes a certain factor of $4\pi$ which must appear either in Maxwell's equations or the Coulomb law).

Comment: Dear @user11374 - you are comparing apples and oranges. The electric charge is something else than the electric current, the electric force is something else than the magnetic force, and a pointlike object is something else than a one-dimensional wire. The two situations are entirely inequivalent. Why do you compare them? They are two different tasks and in natural units, one of the results ends up being 1 times the product or ratio of the letters  and the other ends up being twice a different product. It's just a calculation. There is no similarly natural exercise whose result is half a dyne.

Comment: The comparisons stems from the ratio the give for Lorentz force = v^2/c^2 to the electrostatic force.  dividing the  latter by c^2 should give the former esu^2/c^2. Is this arbitrary? anyway, if is there something basic I am missing, my questions boils down to this : if we divide 1 erg/dyne by esu^2, do we get the pull of one electron on another or the total pull exerted by the two of them? I hope it's clear now.

Comment: What you're doing is correct at most at the level of "having correct units" (dimensional analysis). If you calculate the force between the unit wires with unit currents at a unit distance, the force may simply be calculated and the result is 2 times the letters. not 1 times the letter, so your calculation of the numerical factor is simply wrong. The electrons in the wires are at a general distance - between L and infinity - from each other, and things are complicated, and you have *clearly* not done the right calculation which isn't just the naive multiplication you have sketched.

Comment: @LubošMotl You complain about him comparing apples and oranges yet you seem to compare current and speed yourself. An analogy in computer is bandwidth (current) and latency(speed).

Comment: Dear @user124111, none of my comments included the term "speed" so I couldn't have compared it with something else. Even if I have compared them, it wouldn't be necessarily wrong.